# New to threads : problems using std::ref() in thread parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pass-by-reference

I am new to C++ threads and trying make several objects packed in a `std::vector` call their `prepareForRendering(...)` method asynchronously. It seems I am using `std::ref` wrongly. This works :

```
for (ObjMesh& mesh : this->meshes) {

    // Prepare mesh
    std::thread t(&ObjMesh::prepareForRendering, mesh, pDevice, prepareTextures, prepareVertices, prepareBuffers, filter, addressMode);
    t.join();
}
```

This doesn't :

```
for (ObjMesh& mesh : this->meshes) {

    // Prepare mesh
    std::thread t(&ObjMesh::prepareForRendering, std::ref(mesh), pDevice, prepareTextures, prepareVertices, prepareBuffers, filter, addressMode);
    t.join();
}
```

Compiler throws :

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(238): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(238): note: With the following template arguments:
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(238): note: '_Callable=bool (__thiscall ObjMesh::* )(ID3D11Device *,bool,bool,bool,D3D11_FILTER,D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE)'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(238): note: '_Types={std::reference_wrapper<ObjMesh>, ID3D11Device *, bool, bool, bool, D3D11_FILTER, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE}'
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(247): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Execute<0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7>(std::tuple<bool (__thiscall ObjMesh::* )(ID3D11Device *,bool,bool,bool,D3D11_FILTER,D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE),std::reference_wrapper<ObjMesh>,ID3D11Device *,bool,bool,bool,D3D11_FILTER,D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Target=std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<bool (__thiscall ObjMesh::* )(ID3D11Device *,bool,bool,bool,D3D11_FILTER,D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE),std::reference_wrapper<ObjMesh>,ID3D11Device *,bool,bool,bool,D3D11_FILTER,D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE>,std::default_delete<std::tuple<bool (__thiscall ObjMesh::* )(ID3D11Device *,bool,bool,bool,D3D11_FILTER,D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE),std::reference_wrapper<ObjMesh>,ID3D11Device *,bool,bool,bool,D3D11_FILTER,D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE>>>,
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
```

I need to make sure the `ObjMesh` instance is passed by reference inside the thread.

(I know my thread model makes no sense - this is an example). TYVM.

**EDIT** The prepare for rendering function.

```
bool ObjMesh::prepareForRendering(ID3D11Device* pDevice, bool prepareTextures,  bool prepareVertices, bool prepareBuffers, D3D11_FILTER filter, D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE addressMode);
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `std::ref` for `mesh`, it already is a reference? What the first code does is (essentially) `mesh.prepareForRendering(pDevice, ...)`, the wrapper returned by [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) doesn't support the that semantics.

Comment: `mesh.prepareForRendering(pDevice, ...)` in the first snippet does the work on a copy of `mesh`. My issue being : I need `mesh` to be passed as reference inside the thread. Is that even possible ?

Comment: Or am I plain wrong and the issue is something else ?

Comment: You need to provide the signature of `prepareForRending`.

Comment: I think the issue might be due to the fact that the prepForRendering function creates DX11 buffers I guess *local to it's thread* and gives me a read access violation when attempting to read it from main thread. Does that make sense ?

Comment: By the way, your use of threads is nit parallel but serial. In the loop you create a thread, and then you wait for it to exit before continuing the loop.

Comment: I know that's why I said `(I know my thread model makes no sense - this is an example)`. I am actually storing thread pointers, and loop them / join them (2nd loop) after I looped their instantiation. But the problem seems to be thread local buffers. I can't read them from the main thread it seems - if that makes sense. Ima ask a new question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass pointer to bind:

```
std::thread t(&ObjMesh::prepareForRendering, &mesh, pDevice, prepareTextures, prepareVertices, prepareBuffers, filter, addressMode);
```

Comment: I did but it seems my issue is elsewhere. Does solve my question title tho.